# Making a variable accessible outside of a function in python

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I have been trying to access the "statement" variable in the below codes outside of the function but, it isn't working. I tried making the variable global but anytime I run, it says invalid syntax. I have also tried to make it nonlocal too but still. Can someone please help me.

```
def login():
global email, password

email_var = email.get()
password_var = password.get()

if not email_var or not password_var:
   mb.showerror('Error!', "Please fill in the required field(s)") 
else:
    try:
        global **statement** = f"SELECT ID FROM login WHERE EMAIL='{email_var}' AND PASSWORD = '{password_var}'"
        name =  cx.execute(f"SELECT NAME FROM login WHERE EMAIL='{email_var}' AND PASSWORD = '{password_var}'")
        name_update = name.fetchone()
        cx.execute(statement)
        if not cx.fetchone():
            mb.showerror("Sorry", "Your data is not in our records.")
        else:
            mb.showinfo('Congrats', f"Welcome {name_update}, You successfully logged in.")
            main_win.destroy()
            import main
            return statement
    except:
        mb.showerror('Oops!', 'Looks like there is a problem with your login')
```

Comment: You shouldn't substitute variables directly into SQL queries. Use placeholders and a parameter list in `cx.execute()`.

Comment: Why are you using two different queries to get the ID and name from the same row? Use a single query with `SELECT ID, NAME`

Comment: Why does `statement` need to be global if you return it?

Comment: WHy do you use so many global variables? Learn to use function parameters and return values.

Comment: After returning it, the problem still persisted so I was thinking making it global would solve the problem

Comment: I'm making global variables here, because I have Entry fields with 'email' and 'password' as their variable and so I want to get their values. And also I defined the function before assigning the variables to the entry fields. Or maybe there is another way to do it. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I used two different queries to get the ID to know the user who logged in so I can link that user to another table and the other query to get the name to display in a message box.

Comment: But you can get both of them with a single query. Don't you know that you can list multiple columns in the `SELECT` list?

Answer (score 0):

```
global statement = f"SELECT ID FROM login WHERE EMAIL='{email_var}' AND PASSWORD = '{password_var}'"
```

needs to be two separate lines

```
global statement
statement = f"SELECT ID FROM login WHERE EMAIL='{email_var}' AND PASSWORD = '{password_var}'"
```